# Happyforms name placeholder issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello guys i have 2 questions please ! 
there is this new contact form for wordpress i like it but they have some troubles .
1 - name placeholder can accept any type of values ( numbers - dots and everythings ! any solution to fix that ?

2 - the error messages are showen in a bad way...it is possible to output the error - succes messages in a popup like a bootstrap modal ?

here is the code i found :

function happyforms_message_notices( $location = '' ) {
    $notices = happyforms_get_session()->get_messages( $location );

```
if ( ! empty( $notices ) ) : ?>
    <div class="happyforms-message-notices">
        <?php foreach( $notices as $notice ): ?>
        <div class="happyforms-message-notice <?php echo esc_attr( $notice['type'] ); ?>">
            <h2><?php echo $notice['message']; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
endif;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer at The Theme Foundry, authors of HappyForms.

1. HappyForms doesn't include a "name" part. It also doesn't include an easy way to mask or filter the characters a user can input inside a field. It's doable through the `happyforms_the_part_attributes` filter though, which lets you output a `pattern` html5 attribute.
2. There's no built-in way to output your notices in a modal. I guess you could hack your way through it with Javascript and CSS, although you'll need to modify the original Javascript main file (frontend.js), which I strongly discourage.

Just so you know, you can get in touch with us from both our site and our plugin registry forum, which may be a better fit for your questions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time ago and kinda off problem, not off topic, but you can MonkeyPatch your way into the frontend.js without modifying the original file. This also works with Updates, as long the patched routine does not get Updates.

I have just an example for HappyForms, another demand but still the way you 'can' think about this. Here it's used to Ajax the Response to another location after the request is done by HappyForms.

In general it's not a good behaviour to act like this but sometimes it's the way to go.

```js
/*****************************************************************************************************************
*    .-'-.    Monkey Patching - HappyForms - frontend.js                                                       
*  _/.-.-.\_                                                                                                   
* ( ( o o ) ) HappyForms Class / Just add lines of code after the Form send Post-processing                    
*  |/  '  \|  Should work with Plugin Updates. Check on Updates of the Happy Forms JS if this functions has    
*   \ `-´ /   changed. If so, the Unchanged CODE lines here has to be changed accordingly.                     
*   /`'''`\                                                                                                    
*  /       \  Must be loaded AFTER the original HappyForms JS - frontend.js                                    
*             But before the Form get's initalized by the Page                                                 
*                                                                                                              
*             The used fields can be identified by adding a specific class in the HappyForm Configuration Page
*             Use Property CSS classes for that. Here we assume that there are fields for firstname, lastname and 
*             so on.
******************************************************************************************************************/
HappyForms.Form.prototype.submit = function( e ) {                                             /* Unchanged CODE */
    e.preventDefault();                                                                        /* Unchanged CODE */
                                                                                               /* Unchanged CODE */
    this.$form.addClass( 'happyforms-form--submitting' );                                      /* Unchanged CODE */
    this.$submits.attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );                                              /* Unchanged CODE */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/    
/*Additional CODE */       // Get Data from Happy Forms Field identified by css-class
/*Additional CODE */       let sent_data = { firstName :        '.formdata-firstname' ,
/*Additional CODE */                         lastName :         '.formdata-lastname' ,
/*Additional CODE */                         phoneNo :          '.formdata-phone' ,
/*Additional CODE */                         email :            '.formdata-email'
/*Additional CODE */                       };    
/*Additional CODE */       // Fetch values from inputs
/*Additional CODE */       Object.keys(sent_data).forEach((key,i)=>{ 
/*Additional CODE */                  sent_data[key] = jQuery(sent_data[key]).find('input, textarea, select').val();  
/*Additional CODE */       });  
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    jQuery.ajax( {                                                                             /* Unchanged CODE */
      type: 'post',                                                                            /* Unchanged CODE */
      data: this.serialize( e.target ),                                                        /* Unchanged CODE */
    } ).done( (evt)=>{                                                                         /* Unchanged CODE */
                                                                                               /* Unchanged CODE */
            this.onSubmitComplete( evt );                                                      /* Unchanged CODE */
                                                                                               /* Unchanged CODE */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*Additional CODE */                                             
/*Additional CODE */            /* Additional subroutine to forward data to Cardess */
/*Additional CODE */            console.log('injected code',evt,sent_data);
/*Additional CODE */
/*Additional CODE */            let ajax_url = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
/*Additional CODE */            let wp_action = '[individual ajax function]';
/*Additional CODE */            
/*Additional CODE */            sent_data.action=wp_action;
/*Additional CODE */
/*Additional CODE */            jQuery.ajax({
/*Additional CODE */                  dataType: 'json',
/*Additional CODE */                  url: ajax_url,
/*Additional CODE */                  method:'post',
/*Additional CODE */                  data: sent_data,
/*Additional CODE */                  success: (response)=>{ console.log('Response: ',response);
/*Additional CODE */                                          
/*Additional CODE */
/*Additional CODE */                                       } ,
/*Additional CODE */                  error:(arr)=>{ console.warn('Error sending data');
/*Additional CODE */                                          
/*Additional CODE */                                      }
/*Additional CODE */           });
/*Additional CODE */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
                                                                                               /* Unchanged CODE */
       } );                                                                                    /* Unchanged CODE */
  };                                                                                           /* Unchanged CODE */
/*****************************************************************************************************************/
/* Monkey Patching - DONE                                                                                        */
/*****************************************************************************************************************/
```

I placed it on Github in case of anybody in need of such a solution:

https://github.com/whilexx/MonkeyPatch-WP-HappyForms-ReuseData